# How to make a Kivy GridLayout into scrollview?

Tags: python, user-interface, scroll, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to create a form using Kivy,
[right now it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8aKO.png).

I did it all in one grid layout as follows:

(from the .kv file):

```
<myGrid>:

    GridLayout:

        size: root.width, root.height
        cols:1
        Label:
            text: "Submit Communication Rules"
            size_hint: 0.6,0.3
            font_size: 40

        Label:
            text: "Change URI path:"
            size_hint:0.2,0.3
            font_size: 20
```

...etc...

in the .py file I have:

```
class rules_form(App):
    def build(self):
        return myGrid()


class myGrid(Widget):
```

...

and at the end:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    rules_form().run()
```

as you can see in the pic, many of the widgets got squished, and when I add more with the "+" buttons it gets even worse.

How can I transform it so that it only shows part of the Grid and you have to scroll for the rest? Or any other way to give the widgets more space so they don't get on top of each other like this?

p.s. I tried adding

```
ScrollView:
    do_scroll_x: False
    do_scroll_y: True
    size: root.width, root.height
```

above the `GridLayout` in the .kv file but it looked the same.

Answer (score 0):

You must allow the `GridLayout` to grow. For that, just add these lines to your `GridLayout`:

```
height: self.minimum_height
size_hint_y: None
```

and remove:

```
size: root.width, root.height
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#managing-the-content-size-and-position).

Comment: Did you mean with or without the ScrollView above? I've been trying what you said without the ScrollView above and it only shows me the top of the Grid on the bottom left of the window. I have tried with it too, but that also doesn't seem to work for me. Could you please tell me exactly what to write under ScrollView, and what under GridLayout? I am very new to Kivy. Thanks in advance

Comment: for GridLayout with "height: self.minimum_height" and "size_hint_y: None" [I get this](https://imgur.com/gallery/OrqHoSZ) .
And if I do the same with ScrollView above [I get this](https://imgur.com/gallery/O5ViqbG) . What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `height: self.minimum_height` must be with the child of `ScrollView` (I am guessing that this is the `GridLayout`).  When you use `self.minimum_height`, you must provide enough information for the `GridLayout` to calculate that minimum height. That means that you must specify a height for each child of the `GridLayout`  and `size_hint` (in the `y` direction) will not suffice.